# more than one instance of overloaded function "abs" matches the argument list

Tags: c, sorting

The below code is for dynamic sort in visual code but getting an overload in line 116

*if (  (abs(initial_x1 - cc2->x) < 0.3 && abs(initial_x2 - cc1->x) < 0.3) ) //set this to speed of animation*

**Please note: the same code runs with no error on a mac  which I am confused **
I have tried everything adding **fabs**, **labs**
according to the research I did but the errors keep piling up

any help will be appreciated

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<glut.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define MAX 10
int k = 0;
typedef struct circle
{
    GLfloat x;  //x axis of center
    GLfloat y;  //y axis of center
    GLfloat r;  // radius
}circle;

circle c[MAX];  //array of circles to store the center and radius of each circle
int a[MAX];     // int array for sorting algo
int initial[MAX] = { 10,4,8,6,3,7,9,1,5,2 };    //int array to restore random values after sorting
GLfloat initial_x1, initial_x2; //to set the destiniation for swapping

int global_i = 0, global_j = 0; //i and j values for bubble-sort
int swapping = 0;   //flag to check if circle are being swapped
int sorting = 0;    //start sorting only after user input

void initialise()
{
    global_i = global_j = swapping = 0; //reset all globals
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        a[i] = initial[i];  //if a[] is sorted restore from initial[] 
        c[i].r = a[i] * 4.0;    //4 because to fit 10 circles in screen
        c[i].y = 300.0;     //vertical center of window
        if (i == 0)
            c[i].x = 45.0;  // first circle starts from 45 offset
        else
            c[i].x = c[i - 1].x + 90.0;//(c[i-1].r+c[i].r+10.0); //distance between circles = sum of 2 max readii
        printf("%f - %f - %f\n", c[i].x, c[i].y, c[i].r); //for testing purpose don worry
    }
}

//func to display text on screen char by char
void bitmap_output(int x, int y, const char* string, void* font)
{
    int len, i;

    glRasterPos2f(x, y);
    len = (int)strlen(string);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        glutBitmapCharacter(font, string[i]);
    }
}

//function to integer to string
void int_str(int rad, char r[])
{
    switch (rad)
    {
    case 1: strcpy(r, "1"); break;
    case 2: strcpy(r, "2"); break;
    case 3: strcpy(r, "3"); break;
    case 4: strcpy(r, "4"); break;
    case 5: strcpy(r, "5"); break;
    case 6: strcpy(r, "6"); break;
    case 7: strcpy(r, "7"); break;
    case 8: strcpy(r, "8"); break;
    case 9: strcpy(r, "9"); break;
    case 10: strcpy(r, "10"); break;
    }

}

//draw circle by drawing consecutive triangle fans
void circle_draw(circle c)
{
    float i;
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    glVertex2f(c.x, c.y);   //center of circle
    for (i = 0; i < 360; i += 1)
        glVertex2f(c.x + sin(i) * c.r, c.y + cos(i) * c.r);
    glEnd();

    //display the value of circle below
    int x = c.x - 2;
    int y = c.y - (c.r + 10);
    int rad = c.r / 4;
    char r[3] = "";
    int_str(rad, r);
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    bitmap_output(x, y, r, GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_10);

}

// swaps circles cc1 and cc2 by changing their centers
void swap_circles(circle* cc1, circle* cc2)
{
    if (swapping == 0)  //if circles are not being swapped set destination for each circles
    {
        initial_x1 = cc1->x; //center of circle in left
        initial_x2 = cc2->x; //center of circle in right
        swapping = 1;   //means cicle are being swapped
        printf("%f - %f\n", cc1->r, cc2->r);

    }

    if (initial_x1 <= cc2->x)   //decrease the center of circle in right till its > center of left circle
        cc2->x -= 1.0;      //speed of animation

    if (initial_x2 >= cc1->x)//increase the center of circle in left till its < center of right circle
        cc1->x += 1.0;

    printf("one %f - %f\n", initial_x1, cc2->x);
    printf("two %f - %f\n", initial_x2, cc1->x);

    // if difference between destination and center < 0.3 then cicles are swapped
    if (abs(initial_x1 - cc2->x) < 0.3 && abs(initial_x2 - cc1->x) < 0.3) //set this to speed of animation
    {
        swapping = 0;

        int temp = cc1->x;
        cc1->x = cc2->x;
        cc2->x = temp;

        temp = cc1->y;
        cc1->y = cc2->y;
        cc2->y = temp;

        temp = cc1->r;
        cc1->r = cc2->r;
        cc2->r = temp;
    }

}


void sort() //bubble sort algo
{
    if (!swapping) //if not in process of swappin 2 circles only then get 2 new circles to swap
    {
        while (global_i < 10)
        {
            global_j = global_i;
            while (global_j < 9)
            {
                if (a[global_j] > a[global_j + 1])
                {
                    printf("%d %d\n", global_j, a[global_j]);
                    int temp = a[global_j];
                    a[global_j] = a[global_j + 1];
                    a[global_j + 1] = temp;
                    goto SWAP;

                }
                global_j++;
            }
            global_i++;
        }
    }
SWAP:
    printf("swapping --> %d - %d\n", global_j, global_j + 1);
    bitmap_output(10, 375, "Swapping ->", GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15);

    char r[3] = "";
    int_str(a[global_j], r);
    bitmap_output(150, 375, r, GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15);
    int_str(a[global_j + 1], r);
    bitmap_output(175, 375, r, GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15);

    swap_circles(&c[global_j], &c[global_j + 1]);
}

void display_text()
{
    bitmap_output(200, 565, "DYNAMIC SORTING ALGORITHM VISUALISER", GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24);//title larger font
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP); //to underline the title
    glVertex2f(180, 560);
    glVertex2f(750, 560);
    glEnd();

    //other text small font
    bitmap_output(10, 525, "This program sorts a random set of numbers in ascending order displaying them graphically as ", GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15);
    bitmap_output(10, 505, "circles with varying radii.", GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15);


    if (sorting == 0)//if not sorting display menu
    {
        bitmap_output(10, 455, "MENU", GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15);
        bitmap_output(10, 435, "Press s to SORT", GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15);
        bitmap_output(10, 415, "Press r to RANDOMISE", GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15);
        bitmap_output(10, 395, "Esc to QUIT", GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15);
    }
    else if (sorting == 1)
    {
        glColor3f(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
        bitmap_output(10, 455, "Sorting in progress...", GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15);
        bitmap_output(10, 435, "Please do not quit", GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15);
        glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    }

}

void front()
{
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    bitmap_output(390, 565, "WELCOME!", GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex2f(388, 560);
    glVertex2f(524, 560);
    glEnd();
    bitmap_output(440, 535, "TO", GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex2f(438, 531);
    glVertex2f(475, 531);
    glEnd();

    bitmap_output(200, 495, "DYNAMIC SORTING ALGORITHM VISUALISER", GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex2f(198, 490);
    glVertex2f(731, 490);
    glEnd();
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(594, 120.0); glVertex2f(594, 145); glVertex2f(836, 145); glVertex2f(836, 120.0);
    glEnd();
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    bitmap_output(600, 125, "Press Enter to continue.......", GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18);

}

void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    if (k == 0)
        front();
    else
    {

        display_text();

        glPointSize(2.0);
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        {
            glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
            circle_draw(c[i]);
        }
        if (global_j + 1 < MAX && sorting == 1) // call sort only on key press
            sort();
        else
            sorting = 0;
    }

    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();

}

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    if (key == 13)
        k = 1;
    if (k == 1)
    {
        switch (key)
        {
        case 27: exit(0); //27 is the ascii code for the ESC key
        case 's': sorting = 1; break;
        case 'r': initialise(); break;
        }
    }
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    if (w <= h)
        glOrtho(-2.0, 2.0, -2.0 * (GLfloat)h / (GLfloat)w, 2.0 * (GLfloat)h / (GLfloat)w, -10.0, 10.0);
    else
        glOrtho(-2.0 * (GLfloat)w / (GLfloat)h, 2.0 * (GLfloat)w / (GLfloat)h, -2.0, 2.0, -10.0, 10.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void init(void)
{
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, 900.0, 0.0, 600.0);
}

void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowPosition(50, 50);
    glutInitWindowSize(900, 600);
    glutCreateWindow("Dynamic Sorting Algorithm Visualiser");
    init();
    initialise();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutIdleFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Please read about [mcve]. From the title I expected ~10 lines of code. I didnt even find where `abs` is called in the code you posted

Comment: ok i think this should make it clear
    printf("one %f - %f\n", initial_x1, cc2->x);
    printf("two %f - %f\n", initial_x2, cc1->x);

    // if difference between destination and center < 0.3 then cicles are swapped
    if (abs(initial_x1 - cc2->x) < 0.3 && abs(initial_x2 - cc1->x) < 0.3) //set this to speed of animation
    {
        swapping = 0;

        int temp = cc1->x;

Comment: Why the [C++] tag? Looks much more like C.

Comment: The link I posted above does explain what a minimal reproducible example is. An incomplete snippet of code in a comment isnt one.

Comment: @DanielLangr C would not throw error about overloaded function, so the code is compiled as C++, even if it belongs to the common subset.

Comment: can you please show me the changes I need to make thankyou@463035818_is_not_a_number

Comment: how about soemthing like this: https://godbolt.org/z/xq3GhrjeY. You just need to fill the blanks to fix all errors but the one your question is about

Comment: Could you provide the complete error message? Compilers typically show all candidates when overloading is ambiguous.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I guess the above question I posted is  the problem and error I am unable to fix

Comment: @DanielLangr Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active) E0308 more than one instance of overloaded function "abs" matches the argument list:116

Comment: What is you compiler? Is it a full error description? Is it even a compiler error? EXXXX errors may come from IntelliSense.

Comment: @DanielLangr so basically it is visual code this code is for the dynamic sort in animation

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2668 'abs': ambiguous call to overloaded function Project2 C:\Users\rando\source\repos\Project2\Source.cpp 116

Comment: You can try to compile the code without IDE, just use a compiler in a command line.

Comment: @DanielLangr am sorry i dint get you

Comment: @roropanda I suggest you to compile your source code with your C++ compiler in a command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it was as simple as adding "fabs" instead of "abs"
due to the Foat datatype